# uniformly integrable family of functions equivalent statement

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying the fourth edition of Royden Real Analysis and I have tried to solve the following exercise:

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of function, each of which is integrable over E. Show that $\mathcal{F}$ is uniformly integrable over E if and only if for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for each $f \in \mathcal{F}$,

$$\text{if}\; A \subset E\;\text{is measurable and }m(A)<\delta,\; \text{then}\; \Biggl|\int_Af\Biggr|<\varepsilon.$$

Solution:

The straight direction is obvious. Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is uniformly integrable over E, there is a $\delta>0$such that for each $f \in \mathcal{F}$,

$$\text{if}\; A \subset E\;\text{is measurable and }m(A)<\delta,\; \text{then} \int_A|f|<\epsilon,$$ and therefore, $$\Biggl|\int_Af\Biggr|<\int_A|f|<\epsilon.$$

To show the opposite direction we suppose that for  each $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for each $f \in \mathcal{F}$,

$$\text{if}\; A \subset E\;\text{is measurable and }m(A)<\delta,\; \text{then}\; \Biggl|\int_Af\Biggr|<\varepsilon.$$ We also know that every $f \in \mathcal{F}$ is integrable so for fixed $f \in \mathcal{F}$ and fixed $\epsilon$, there is a $\delta_f>0$ such that, 
$$\text{if}\; A \subset E\;\text{is measurable and }m(A)<\delta_f,\; \text{then}\; \int_A|f|<\epsilon.$$

My problem is that I cannot find a common $\delta$ for all $f$ to show the desire.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126215/an-equivalent-definition-of-uniform-integrability?rq=1).

Comment: You're welcome.